# The Meaning of “~” in Definitions

Tags: dictionary

The symbol “~” appears in many definitions. What does it mean? 
Examples:

```
2   纯；专：专～。～心～意。
```

https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E4%B8%80

---

```
1   头的前部，脸：脸～。颜～。～目。～～相觑。
```

https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E9%9D%A2

---

```
2   旧时指读书人：～子。～民。学～。
```

https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E5%A3%AB

---

UPDATE:
And, what does it mean when there are two consecutive swung dashes? Such as in:  “～～相觑。”

Comment: it stands for repeated head word in dictionary entries, see dictionary's "Guide to the Use of the Dictionary": "~ represents the word of each entry"

Comment: note ～ represents the head word, which need not be a single character, e.g.气量，。。。他～大，他～小，混 ～合（＝混合）。。。～饲料（＝混合饲料）

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of this *swung dash* means the entry character or word is used in the corresponding words.

> 2 旧时指读书人：～子。～民。学～。

... is equivalent to:

> 2 In olden times, refers to educated people. 士子。士民。学士。

This is a common typographical convention, used in many dictionaries [globally](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=swung%20dash&sub=Search%20WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=000000000000), including in [English](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/153769).

EDIT: for reduplication or for other forms of repeat of the entry, the swung dash is often repeated, viz for 面

> ~ ~ 相觑

... is equivalent to

> 面面相觑.

Comment: Thanks. What about when there are two consecutive swung dashes. Such as in:  头的前部，脸：脸～。颜～。～目。～～相觑。

Comment: how about ＂each instance of ～represents one instance of head word of entry＂ ? e.g. **面** ，。。。。。，～～相觑＝面面相觑

Comment: @user6065 Good point; have edited my answer.